# Perl variable to Powershell script

Tags: perl, powershell

I want to use a variable from my perl script to my powershell script to avoid two manipulations similar but i don't know how do that ...

Perl :

```
#
# main
#


### KeyPress ###
print "Indiquer l'adresse repertoire de la base a traiter :";
chomp(my $saisie = <STDIN>);

#script dezippage powershell
my $powershellPath ="c:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
my $filePath ="c:\\Strawberry\\unzipper.ps1";
system("$powershellPath $filePath",$saisie);
```

Powershell :

```
Write-Host "UNZIPPER `n"
$base = Read-Host "Saisir l'adresse repertoire de la base à traiter" # i want to replace by $saisie

#Recuperation listes de document de la base
$documents = Get-ChildItem $base
```

Can you help me please for fix my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your PowerShell script, declare `$base` as a parameter with a default value of `$(Read-Host)`:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Position=0)]
  $base = $(Read-Host "Saisir l'adresse repertoire de la base à traiter")
)
Write-Host "UNZIPPER `n"

#Recuperation listes de document de la base
$documents = Get-ChildItem $base
```

When you invoke it with `system()` and pass the argument, it'll automatically get bound to the `$base` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can give system a list of arguments so for you it would be something like

```
@cmd = ();
push(@cmd,"c:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe");
push(@cmd,"c:\\Strawberry\\unzipper.ps1");
push(@cmd,$saisie);
system(@cmd);
```

Take a look at http://perlmaven.com/running-external-programs-from-perl

Or you can roll your own command as below, and not use system

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $test = command("ls -l");
print $test;

sub command($) {

        undef $/;

        my $command = shift;

        open(COMMAND, "| $command");
        my $content = <COMMAND>;
        close(COMMAND);

        return $content;
}
```